# 2.78c | Changing fluid gravity direction results in really weird behaviour

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have a rather simple fluid simulation.
My gravity is at -9.81, and it works nice, but I have animated the gravity and when it changes from -0.001 to 0 or a value greater than 0 the simulation breaks totally.

Frame 144, gravity at -0.001 **—** Frame 145, gravity at 0

[image: fluid breaking]

And it stays that way the rest of the simulation.
**I do need** the gravity to change for this, and I just don't know what is going on and no one seems to have this problem.

I'm using Blender 2.78c

[Here's a link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5hf7mSQkdaHR3RqeklVVWRNeW8) to a Drive folder with the blend file and ZIP with both the blend file and simulation cache.

Thanks!